# Where is libzmq header file?

Tags: zeromq

I compiled and installed libzmq on my Raspberry pi but I can't find the C-binding header file, `czmq.h`.

I searched the entire file system and only find the libary files in `/usr/local/lib`.

https://linux.die.net/man/7/czmq

Answer (score 1):

You have to install `czmq` also, it's a separate library and it is not included with `libzmq`: http://czmq.zeromq.org